# symfony - querybuilder in controller

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, load

I am using the querybuilder in my controller to receive data and output as json:

```
    $qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $qb = $qb->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('c')
        ->from('AppBundle:Customer\Customer', 'c');

    $data = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData(
        [
            'data' => $data
        ]
    );

    return $response;
```

My Entity is in namespace:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Customer;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Customer\Repository")
 */
class Customer {

....
```

There are two records saved in table.

When I load the url it just print two empty array´s and no data.

Anybody could explain why?

Comment: Objects are not going to be automatically serialized.  replace getResult with getArrayResult http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats Later you mught want to read up on serializers: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html or http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php

Answer (score 2):

Try this and then extract it......

```
$response = new JsonResponse(); 
$response->setData(array( 'data' => $data ));
```

Comment: How is this different from what is in the question?